# Some Tailwind CSS styles are not working on a website, but work correctly in the Tailwind playground

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have been using Tailwind CSS on my website and now some styles are not been applying there. However, when I use them on the Tailwind playground they work.

For example:

```html
<footer class=" bg-lime-600 ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</footer>
```

This background color is not being applied to the website, but in the Tailwind playground it works.

Comment: How is your tailwind configured or have you downloaded the full tailwind css if not, the tailwind css is generated as you use it and for that you'd need to have the listener active in nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking:

- The code the file is in is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.
- The class name is not built via string concatenation/interpolation – class names must appear as complete unbroken strings.
- `blue-500` or `blue.500` exists as a color in your Tailwind configuration.
- `bg-blue-500` would resolve to a Tailwind class candidate. This might not be the case if you have customized your Tailwind configuration in a certain way.
- There is not some other CSS on the page that may interfere with the Tailwind class, perhaps overriding the Tailwind rule.
- Tailwind has run a compilation since you added the class name. Try restarting the dev/watch task if you have it running.
- The element in question is visible on the page.